# Criteria for preflight

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, browser, cors

[image]

Came across this image while searching to avoid preflight OPTION calls on this URL : https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Obviously Browser is deciding whether a preflight is necessary or not? I want to understand when and how a browser decides a preflight request?

Thanks.